# Average the numerical values where an identifier column meets a condition in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

In Excel 2007, I have a table with numbers in Columns F, G, H, I, and J. There is an identifier in Column B.

I need the average of all numbers in Columns F, G, H, I, and J where the identifier in Column B = A14 (i.e. the value in A14).

I tried the following:

```
=AVERAGEIFS('Hours-Backup'!F3:J1048576,'Hours-Backup'!B:B,'Group Dashboard'!A14)
```

This results in a **`#VALUE!`**  error.

Ultimately, I want to make it so that the function ignores all cells that are non-numeric or blank. In other words, I don't want it to assume that blank cells are 0 for averaging purposes.

I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts. You should use the [contact form](https://superuser.com/contact) and select "I need to merge accounts" to have your accounts merged. In order to merge them you will need to provide links to the two accounts, for your information these are http://superuser.com/users/439916/xlslearner and http://superuser.com/users/440116/xlslearner. You'll then be able to edit, comment on and accept answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems.  (Or one problem with two heads.)  `AVERAGEIFS` help says:

> - Unlike the range and criteria arguments in the AVERAGEIF function,
>     in AVERAGEIFS each criteria_range must be the same size and shape as sum_range.

Well, that’s a typo: “sum_range” should be “average_range”. 
But, anyway, that’s your problem: your criteria range is 1×∞ (an entire column)
and your average range is 5×1048574. 
So you can fix one of the problems by changing `B:B` to `B3:B1048576`,
making it a 1×1048574 range.

You could solve the second problem
by replicating Column `B` into Columns `C`, `D`, `E`, and `F`,
and then using `B3:F1048576` as your criteria_range.  But that’s crazy. 
The reasonable way is to define a helper column (let’s say `V`)
to be the average of Columns `F`-`J` on the current row:

- Set `V3` to `AVERAGE(F3:J3)`,
- and drag down.

Then get your conditional average by averaging the averages:

```
=AVERAGEIFS('Hours-Backup'!V3:V1048576,'Hours-Backup'!B3:B1048576,'Group Dashboard'!A14)
(changes)                  ^  ^                        ^  ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach to situations like this is a couple of helper columns and some array formulas. Hopefully I've set this toy sheet up in the same way as yours:

[image: Excel snip]

Here I've set up `A16` as the cell to set which filtered rows you want to retain. `B` is the column of values to filter against, `C` through `G` are the columns with values that may be missing.  I count the number of values present in each row in column `H`, and sum the values that are present in column `I`.  Cells `H2` and `I2` sum the respective 'Count' and 'Sum' columns, and then the resulting average is computed in `K2`.  Note that the formulas in columns `H` and `I` are nicely robust to both text and error values within the table.

I'm not sure of the version compatibility of the `SUM(IF(...))` construction within array formulas.  It clearly works on Excel 2010 and should probably also work on Excel 2007, and on Excel 2013.